# How to handle YYYYMM data in Impala?

Tags: bigdata, impala

I have data sources that provide date information in the format YYYYMM, for example, 201805. What is the best Impala datatype to deal with such data?

I could use string but that would restrict the ability to do date math on that data field.

Please suggest.

Comment: Whats wrong with Timestamp?

Comment: YYYYMM - is not a date. 201805 - is not a date And string does not restrict date math because string can be converted to date if you know how.

Comment: impala doesn't have a timestamp datatype ...for such cases, we  use int only